# EM dash ("–") gets replaced by character â€” upon update in WinCvs

Tags: version-control, repository, cvs, dvcs, cvsnt

In WinCvs, when I take update of a file (in my case its .sql file) the EM Dash (**–**) gets replaced by character **â€”**. How can I get rid of this?
I am using **WinCvs version - 2.1.1.1(Build 1)**

Comment: Looks like CVS doesn't like Unicode, could you get away with using a hyphen/minus instead?

Comment: No.. there are hundreds of .sql files already available in repo and its tough and time consuming to replace each and every em dash with hyphen/minus

Comment: Is it actually getting replaced, or is it just displaying with the wrong encoding? (And in 2018, why are you using CVS?!?)

Comment: @ Marnen Laibow-Koser, its actually getting replaced. I am working on a product which is quite old and its using CVS..!